# jQueryUI datepicker issue in append method

Tags: append, jquery-ui-datepicker

okay so i have this page im making, the navigation panel is simple, when i click a link according the the link name it appends the html into the content area, here is the append script for this section

So my goal is where the input box is the ID datepicker im trying to use the jQueryUI datepicker function from jQuery, i tested a regular input box in the actual BODY and not through the append method and it works fine, my issue is im guessing the single vs the double qoutation marks, the ' vs "

how can i solve this issue?

```
 else if (this.id == "tour"){

        $("#content").empty();

        $("#content").append("<p>\

            <h2> Add Tour Dates </h2>\

            <form action='tourdates.php' method='post'>\

            <input type='text' name='title' placeholder='Title' id='title'>\

            <input type='text' name='venueName' placeholder='Vanue Name' id='venueName'>\

            <input type='text' name='venueStreetAdress' placeholder='Location Street Adress' id='venueStreetAdress'>\

            <input type='text' name='venueCity' placeholder='City' id='venueCity'>\

        <input type='text' name='venueState' placeholder='State' id='venueState'>\

            <input type='text' name='venueZip' placeholder='Postal Code' id='venueZip'>\

            <input type='text' name='datepicker' id='datepicker'>\

            <input type='text' name='time' placeholder='Time' id='time'> </p>\

            ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strong feeling that there's something to do with your quotation mark, try to narrow down the problem: Have you tried to put this in a separated variable and make the reference there?

```
var htmlStuff = "<p>\
    <h2> Add Tour Dates </h2>\...";
$("#content").append(htmlStuff);
```

But I don't think your problem is related to double/single quotes, but with the asynchronous operation of setting up a link to append HTML and try to assign an UI widget before the components exist in the DOM.

Although I find this very bad for code readability, one option would be to append another call to a function that defines the DatePicker (like a "callBack") right after your append. It should work, e.g.:

```
$('something').append(" <html stuff> ").defineDatePicker();

function defineDatePicker(){
    $('one of the elements within that html stuff').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: im going to try to append my HTML in a different way, by using a hiddin div within the body and calling a function to display the inner html of that div, BUT i will try out your method as well just to see how it plays out and get back to you ASAP. Thanks very much for your assistance!

Comment: Just an update, your answer solved my issue if i were to of used my orginal method of appending but i have now came up with a new better way to append stuff so i wont be using this method, i'll come back later and post a link to my new method of appending when ive perfected it. Thanks for your help @theMarceloR